# Transform identical data frame rows into a summarized version

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to transform the following data frame:

```
data = [['bob', 1], ['joe', 4], ['joe', 1], ['bob', 3], ['joe', 7]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'score'])
print(df)
```

(that looks like below)

```
  name  score
0  bob      1
1  joe      4
2  joe      1
3  bob      3
4  joe      7
```

into this summarized version:

```
  name  min  max  mean
0  bob    1    3     2
1  joe    1    7     4
```

i.e. just one row per name and reporting summary statistics of the rows

I am pretty sure there must be an easy pythonic way instead of slow loop constructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a list of aggregate functions to `agg`, this will get your desired output.

```
df.groupby('name')['score'].agg(['min','max','mean']).reset_index()

  name  min  max  mean
0  bob    1    3     2
1  joe    1    7     4
```